# Test Map Output Schema wrong

Tags: mapping, biztalk, biztalk-2010

This is a bit of a strange one, but I was wondering if anyone might have seen it before and know of a cure.

Basically, we have updated a schema and the format has radically changed.  The schema was used in a number of maps, so these have also been updated.

When testing one of the maps (Visual Studio right click, test map) it claims that the test suceeds, but the resultant xml is in the old schema format and not the new updated format.

The mapper shows the correct schema, I have tried rebuilding and even redeploying just in case something was holding on to the old schema somehow, but it still maps to the old format.

Any suggestions welcome.

Cheers
Stu.

Comment: So, I've managed to fix this, but I don't know how or why it happened!

Comment: I changed the test input message to another sample and the map worked.  Changing the input message back to the original test case now also produces the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

This is a <del>bug</del> [feature](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkr2adapters/thread/f9689b84-93ad-447a-bb5c-81d0816a620a/) of Visual Studio BizTalk projects.

In your BizTalk solution, ensure that "show all files" (at the top) is set, and then manually run through your affected Schemas, and delete the generated `.xsd.cs` files.

Do the same for your updated maps (`btm.cs`) as well, and then rebuild the project.
(BizTalk will rebuild the *.cs files)

Also, at deployment / import time, ensure that you:

- Re-GAC your assemblies
- Re start the BizTalk host processes